# Ansible gather IPs of nodes in cluster

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Here is a simple cluster inventory:

```
[cluster]
host1
host2 
host3
```

Each host has an `interface` configured with ipv4 address. This information could be gathered with `setup` module and will be in `ansible_facts.ansible_{{ interface }}.ipv4.address`.

How do to get IPv4 addresses for `interface` from each individual host and make them available to each host in `cluster` so that each host knows all cluster IPs?

How this could be implemented in a role?

Comment: This information is *already* available to each host in the cluster by using [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).

Answer (score 0):

As @larsks already commented, the information is available in hostvars. If you, for example, want to print all cluster IPs you'd iterate over `groups['cluster']`:

```
- name: Print IP addresses
  debug:
    var: hostvars[item]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address']
  with_items: "{{ groups['cluster'] }}"
```

Note that you'll need to gather the facts first to populate `hostvars` for the cluster hosts. Make sure you have the following in the play where you call the task (or in the role where you have the task):

```
- name: A play
  hosts: cluster
  gather_facts: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while on how to make list variables with Jinja2. Here is complete solution that requires `cluster_interface` variable and pings all nodes in cluster to check connectivity:

```
---
- name: gather facts about {{ cluster_interface }}
  setup:
    filter: "ansible_{{ cluster_interface }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  delegate_facts: True
  with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
  when: hostvars[item]['ansible_' + cluster_interface] is not defined

- name: cluster nodes IP addresses
  set_fact:
    cluster_nodes_ips: "{{ cluster_nodes_ips|default([]) + [hostvars[item]['ansible_' + cluster_interface]['ipv4']['address']] }}"
  with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"

- name: current cluster node IP address
  set_fact:
    cluster_current_node_ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_' + cluster_interface]['ipv4']['address'] }}"

- name: ping all cluster nodes
  command: ping -c 1 {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ cluster_nodes_ips }}"
  changed_when: false
```